# how to solve java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object; in java

Tags: java

I'm getting values through query and next i'm trying to iterating values but is throws error

```
Session session = null;
   try{
     Query qu=session.createSQLQuery("select plot_no from house_details where type='duplex'");
    List<Long> li =  qu.list();
    System.out.println("---li---"+li.toString());
    for (Iterator itr = li.iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
        Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
        String plotNo = (String) obj[0];
        if(plotNo=="501" || plotNo== "520" || plotNo== "601"){
        System.out.println("---if---");
        //code here
        }
        else{
        System.out.println("---else---");
        //code here
        }
    }
 }catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();

   }finally {
       if(session!=null){
        session.close();
     }
    }
```

**output:**

```
---li---[501, 0, 101, 101, 114]
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

what is wrong in my code. Error getting this lines

```
Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
String plotNo = (String) obj[0];
```

Comment: You cant cast Lang to array object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The call to `itr.next` returns a `BigDecimal`, not an `Object[]`. You are trying to cast it to an `Object[]`:

```
Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
String plotNo = (String) obj[0];
```

You get a `ClassCastException` because it is not an `Object[]`.

Replace the two lines above with this one line:

```
String plotNo = itr.next().toString();
```

Comment: Thank you it's working fine. but always going to **else** loop any problem in my **if** loop condition

Comment: @Sri Don't compare strings with `==` in Java. You need to use `equals` instead. See [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: i'm got **101** two times it is going in **else** loop also two times,how to stop it i want only one time is enough

Comment: @Sri if you want unique numbers then specify that in your SQL: `select distinct plot_no from ...`

Comment: Thank you it is working fine,but some scenarios i got **501, 520, 101, 101, 114,620** values,so each value checking **if** and **else** conditions and entered all times in two loops,i want once enter any loop on that it's stop the checking.Are You understand?

Answer (score 1):

```
Object[] obj = (Object[]) itr.next();
String testName = (String) obj[0];
```

You expect that java understands what you want to do. Frequently it will be true, and it is described in documentation. Actually, method toString() is called when another method obtains string as arg. In your case you expect something similar on unboxing and boxing( it is only true for Object class). And method toString() won't be called.

try to use 
method toString() explicitly which exist in class Object and all classes inherit this. It is made special for this case.

```
String testName = obj[0].toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use

```
String testName = obj[0].toString();
```

Regards
Mahesh